# Horizontally and Vertically align a span element

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/2/)

```
  <div class="subject" index= "0">
        <span class="subject_name">FIFA</span>
        <span class="subject_completion">55%</span>
    </div>

.subject span
{ 
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why it is not vertically aligning my span div? How do i align it vertically which should not affect horizontal aligning also?

I am not preferring using top, `margin-top`, `padding-top`. I am preferring something which should work even size of my circle changes.

I am free to modify html also, but i am first preferring span instead div.

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: are you trying to vertically align the text inside the span (which it appears to be doing) or vertically align the `span` inside the div?

Comment: Yes. @SamiaRuponti. Even though content increases, i want it aligned properly. That's why i am not preferring top

Answer (score 9):

You don't need any special rules at all for the `span`s. You can just add these three rules to the container:

```css
.subject {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.user_body_content_container
{
    display: table;
}

.subject_container
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: table-cell;
}

.subject
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #653;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_body_content_container">
    <div class="subject_container" id="subject_container0" index="0">
        <div class="subject" index= "0">
            <span class="subject_name">FIFA</span>
            <span class="subject_completion">55%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks. Flex browser compatibility? Supports all the major browsers?

Comment: `flex` is awesome, but of course, IE support starts from IE10.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

you have too many display: table and display: table-cell for the task you're doing.

try

```
.user_body_content_container
{

}

.subject_container
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    /*remove above*/
}

.subject
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #653;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.subject span
{ 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luongatoolz/e4b3kd3k/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS classes.

```
.user_body_content_container
{
    display: table;
}

.subject_container
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    position:absolute;
}

.subject
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #653;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;

}

.subject span
{ 
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution I came up with:

css:

```
body, html{
margin:0; padding:0;height:100%
}
.user_body_content_container{
height:100%;
}
.subject_container{
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
vertical-align:middle
}
.subject 
{ 
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;}
.subject span{border:1px solid black;width:175px; display:inline-block}
/*no height given, to give it room to adjust for long texts*/
```

tested it with long text and short text and it appears to be working.

Note: 100% heights are required in the container `div's and body to make the page full height.

here's the codepen: http://tinyurl.com/klzknog

Comment: Can You please add a fiddle or add run snippets here?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways for vertical align: flexbox, display: table-cell and position.

HTML

```
<div class="container one">
  <p>I'm a text</p>
</div>
<div class="container two">
  <p>I'm a text</p>
</div>
<div class="container three">
  <p>I'm a text</p>
</div>
```

CSS (Sass)

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  float: left;
  margin-right:1em;
}

.one {
  display: table;
    p {
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

.two {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.three {
  position: relative;
  p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVRaPM)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to the parent class

```
.subject{
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this would align the span both horizontally and vertically